# How do I change my organisation's address in a mailing?

Tags: civimail, tokens

I want to send out a civi mailing relating to a change of office address - the trouble is, the required {domain.address} refers to the old address and I can't see how to change this?

Is there a quick way?

Thanks, 
James

Comment: Edited the title to make it clearer for other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can change your organization address by going to
Administer > Communications > Organization Address and contact info.

Alternatively and less recommended,you can disable the check for mandatory tokens in CiviMail by going to:
Administer > Civimail > Civimail component settings